# Django model inheritance for closely related objects

Tags: python, django, relationship

I'm not sure about the "proper" way to define the relationship between a two closely related, hierarchy-based objects.

I'm developing a kind of forum-like framework in Django.

My initial idea was that, since a Thread is basically a "special" kind of Post, I should just create a fully-featured Post model, and then have a Thread model inherit from it, extended with any fields a Thread might need. Like so:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default="")

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Thread(Post):
    thread_views = models.IntegerField()
    reply_count = models.IntegerField()
    (...)
```

I also thought about making a single "Post" model with a "isThread" boolean field, but something didn't feel right about it.

I've seen in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) an example that seems very related, but it does say that the objects are stored in separate tables, and I'm not sure if that's the best choice for this kind of design.

What would be the "proper" way to do this, performance-wise and good-practices-wise?

Comment: It depends if you're going to actually save `Post` objects in your database. If you are going to have both `Posts` and `Threads` then you are doing the right thing. If not and you think you might have other kinds of Posts in the future, you might want to make `Post` an [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) that needs to be subclassed. Using something like `is_thread` isn't optimal, since this means the specific `Thread` fields would have to be optional and you need to write all validation rather than rely on model validation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definitions.

What's the difference between a `Thread` and a `Post` - is a `Thread` just a `Post` with replies? or does a `Post` have to belong to a `Thread` ?

For me, I'd say that a `Post` could be in reply to another `Post`, so might need a nullable `reply_to` `FK('self')` field.

That way you could have a single `Post` with many replies, thus creating a thread, and you could allow replies to replies (or not, depending on your use case).

For storing view counts and so on, you could store that in some sort of time series way (that way you could know how popular a post is over time, rather than a single integer, as well as being able to do a simple count operation to get total views for instance)

```
class PostActions:
    post (link to Post)
    action ('view', 'like', 'click' etc)
    timestamp (auto_now)
```

Many ways to do it!

Comment: You're right, I should've been more specific. A `Thread` is indeed just a `Post` with replies. A `Post` can be a reply to another `Post`, so long as both `Post`s belong to the same `Thread`.

Comment: In that case there's no real common fields between a `Thread` and a `Post` and you should just have two separate model classes and a FK relationship between a `Post` and a `Thread`